# 6 distinguishable balls into 5 distinguishable boxes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to put the balls so that every box has at least 1 ball.I had seen a solution to the answer, however I am not sure why my method doesn't work, of 6!*5, which like putting one ball into each box then the remaining one anywhere.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Could you put all the balls in one box?

Comment: @lulu sorry I had forgotten to add the context of the question

Comment: So, edit your post to include all the relevant information.

Comment: If you want a cheap answer:  guessing that you can't have empty boxes, then you are off by a factor of $2$, since you double count every solution.  If balls $b_1, b_2$ are in Box $1$ then you count  twice by first having $b_2$ as the "remaining one" and second by having $b_1$ as the "remaining one".

Comment: ah right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the end you will have four boxes with one ball each, one box with two balls.

Pick the two balls that will be together. There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of doing that. Then pick which box they are in; there are $5$ ways of choosing. Now place the remaining $4$ balls into the remaining $4$ boxes: there are $4!$ ways of doing *that*. Total: $\binom{6}{2}\times 5 \times 4! = \binom{6}{2}5!$.